# Export each individual frame as .GLB file

Tags: scripting

I'm looking to find a way (if necessary use a script) to export each frame from a 1000 frame timeline as a single framed .GLB file. How can I do this?

It's easy to do as exporting as .PNG, since each frame is its own image, but how would I accomplish this with .GLB since it wants to export the entire timeline with it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this script

```py
import bpy

# First frame to export
frame_start = 1

# Last frame to export
frame_end = 1000

# Filename
filename = "my-model"

for f in range(frame_start, frame_end + 1):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
        filepath="%s.f%04d.glb" % (filename, f),
        export_animations=False,
        export_current_frame=True,
    )
```

The GLBs will be named like `my-model.f0001.glb`, `my-model.f0002.glb`, etc.